# How to get a list of loaded scripts, including the ones dynamically loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to match a certain script with the currently loaded scripts on the page:

```
if($('script[src="' + sn + '"]').length == 0)
  $('head').append('<scr' + 'ipt src="' + sn +'"></scr' + 'ipt>');
```

This works but only for scripts that were loaded normally.

For scripts that were injected using javascript, like the one in my condition, it doesn't work :(

Apparently scripts that are loaded this way are somehow invisible in the DOM, even though they run.

Comment: *How* were the scripts dynamically loaded?

Comment: like I wrote above, with append('...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var isThere = false;
$("script").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("src") == sn) {
        isThere = true;  
        // this works also with injected scripts!!
    }
});
if (isThere === false) {
    $('head').append('<scr' + 'ipt src="' + sn +'"></scr' + 'ipt>');
}
```

Comment: This potentially includes the "sn" script as often as there are other `script` tags, i.e. multiple times.

Comment: This would append the new script multiple times for every other script that doesn't match it.

Comment: no, it doesn't. sn will run, but it won't be visible in the DOM after you appended it. Try running that condition again later and you'll see that you get two requests for that file...

Comment: Alex, what I'm saying is that if there are multiple script tags in the file, the condition in your `if` statement will be true multiple times, thus triggering your code that does the `.append()` multiple times.

Comment: Suppose the third script matches sn.  You will do the append twice before on the first two (that do not match) and then you will find one that matches.  I don't think that's what the OP wants to do.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to know reliably what script elements have been loaded because once a script element is loaded and executed, it can be removed with zero effect on the document. Also, script elements inserted usig the *innerHTML* property don't get executed, so their presence is meaningless (more or less).

All you can do is get a list of the current script elements in the document, you can't reliably know which ones have been loaded or even executed.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you test for the existence of something in your script (such as a global variable name, a global object or a function name).

```
if (!window.functionName) {
    // script holding functionName must not be present so load it dynamically
}
```

Comment: the only problem is that I don't know what scripts will be on the page :)

Comment: You do know what script you're trying to include if it's not already there, right?  You can just look in it and see what's in it and pick some indicator to test for.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use the PerformanceAPI:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/getEntries

Answer (score 0):

You can check array of entries

```
const entries = performance.getEntries();
```

This entry includes properties

```
// entries[0];

{
  detail: null,
  duration: 1586,
  entryType: "measure",
  name: "Next.js-before-hydration",
  startTime: 0
}
```